# Replacing ROI with another ROI

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am working on video processing project in its intermediate phase requires replacing ROI of some image with ROI (same dimension) of another image. Is there any built in functions for that??

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Mat::copyTo` to transfer stuff between Mat instances:

```
cv::Mat image1, image2;

cv::Rect roi1(0, 0, 100, 100);
cv::Rect roi2(50, 50, 150, 150);

cv::Mat(image2, roi2).copyTo(cv::Mat(image1, roi1));
```